# How do I increase my exported video quality?

Tags: export, output

It is my first time using Final Cut Pro and I am having trouble exporting a high quality video. The clips I used to make the video are QuickTime screen recording and they are very high quality, and when I was exporting the video, I got these settings:

[image]

Which I believe it's pretty good as well, but the outputted video is only 839.4M rather than 8G and it's not as good as its original resolution and it has big black paddings around the video. Here's what it looks like in full screen in my QuickTime player:
[image]

I've googled it and it seems like I should modify the project's settings [Final Cut Pro X: Modify a project’s settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07mRg.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07mRg.png): https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12526?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US "Final Cut Pro X: Modify a project’s settings", but this thing is greyed out in my FCPX:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of my editor window:
[image]

So, what exactly should I do to output my video with at least its original quality?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

to get the best quality export from FCPX choose the option from the CODEC "Source = ProRes 422" and then see if that gives you any better results.

Alternatively you can choose the option
Format = Computer then export from there